# Adding a static route with networkd

Tags: linux-networking, systemd

I'm trying to use systemd-networkd to configure a static route. The actual IPs are different, but here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
ip route add 10.17.12.0/23 dev eth0
```

If I run this command, my networking setup works exactly as intended. I just need to establish connectivity between this host and the 10.17.12.0 subnet. My host is on a different subnet, and it cannot route there on its own for some reason. Now I want to take that same static route and configure it via a systemd-networkd file.

Here is the config I've tried using

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Route]
Gateway=10.2.100.5 # IP address of eth0 interface
Destination=10.17.12.0/23
```

I have also tried with Gateway set to the default gateway for the eth0 interface, but every time I get the same error:

```
eth0: Could not set route: Invalid argument
```

Any ideas what I could be doing here?

Comment: Did you configure a route to 10.2.100.5? The kernel needs to know how to route traffic to the gateway, in order to use it as such for another route. Though in this case I would expect the error message `Could not set route: Network is unreachable`.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `ip route add 10.17.12.0/23 dev eth0`, you'll get this in `ip route show`:

```
10.17.12.0/23 dev eth0 scope link
```

Note the `scope link` part.

So try this in your `networkd` configuration:

```
[Route]
Destination=10.17.12.0/23
Scope=link
```

Specifying a dummy gateway address should not be necessary then.